# Add products via REST API to Magento 2 webshop

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, import-products

I want to add products to my webshop via a REST API.

I have the following [API documentation](https://www.floraathome.nl/api-documentatie/v1/) available.

Ofcourse, I also have a API token and Test API token.

My question is, how can I import the product data to my Magento 2 webshop via the REST API? How can I connect to right fields with each other? Hopefully someone can help me or give me a direction.

Thanks! :-)